# Typescript loses specificity of key type when accessing mapped Proxy object

Tags: typescript, string, mapped-types

**TL;DR** Can I prevent `key` from widening to `string`?

```
type Foo = {
  [key in string]: key
}
type Test = Foo['bar']
//   ^? type Test = string
```

How can I have `Test` be of type `'bar'` instead of `string`?

---

I'm trying to type a `Proxy` intended for accessing an API. This API has some endpoints that are known in advance, and some that are not. For this reason I need the proxy to work on known strings (`'a' | 'b' | 'c'`) and unknown strings (`string`).

I start with a "schema" of the known endpoints:

```
type Paths = {
    '/a/b/{id}': {}
    'foo/bar': {}
}
```

And I have this type that will infer the "dynamic parts" of a URL:

```
type ExtractParams<url extends string> = 
    url extends `${string}{${infer A extends string}}${string}`
        ? {[param in A]: string}
        : {}

type test = ExtractParams<'/a/b/{foo}'>
//   ^? type test = { foo: string }
```

When trying to type the `Proxy`, I need to return types for both "known" and "unknown" endpoints, so I'm doing something like this:

```
type MyProxy = {
    [key in keyof Paths]: ExtractParams<key>
} & {
    [key in string]: ExtractParams<key>
}
```

Which allows for accessing *any string*:

```
MyProxy['/a/b/{id}'] // known from `Paths`, no issue
MyProxy['/la/la/la'] // unknown from `Paths`, no issue
```

But the issue is that typescript is unable to correctly "infer the dynamic parts" of unknown endpoints because it just types them as `string`:

```
type knownPathParam = MyProxy['/a/b/{id}']
//   ^? type knownPathParam = { id: string } <-- correct, because `/a/b/{id}` is in Paths

type unknownPathParam = MyProxy['/d/e/{id}']
//   ^? type unknownPathParam = {}           <-- incorrect, we would want `{ id: string }`
```

As we've seen above `ExtractParams` works regardless of which string we pass it, the issue comes from the fact that any key coming from `key in string` just gets boiled down to `string` instead of "retaining its value":

```
type BasicDemo = {
    [key in string]: key
}

type test = BasicDemo['some specific string']
//   ^? type test = string
```

**Is there a way for `key` to retain the type of the "specific string" being accessed here?**

[link to a typescript playground of this demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGCGwAsDOUC8UDeBYAUFfUA5APSzEBGxGAlgCYC+hAXJvbgUQGYD23FsAJ2atcbHLlCQoAUQAewAbADGwAAqDYAWyQAeAK4CANlAjyIAO1ookC6uYDmAPjRQDx08AtWoAAwAkGDYCdvb0GAF2nBACUACCJmaW1rYO9PQBQSH0PuwcBAD8mADacIqaUHZxALosmam5eVAsGGIS4NAAsiCqAtyyIC7YeARFANYQA5XjINycMPDINTLyiirqZbrTjqJQAGSYDVBjExXmUHX2S3IKymoa2jpborhtUqPm3ADu5uqI61ouLo9PogIokMiUGgMQhVXDEYgEAB6+ReOEk0D05neXx+C3+5XQQN6-TBxFoxAgVDojFhOHhSJR4iZ6KgACFYEhqEoACIQTTcQaHY6TM4XJbTZ7M9pQTw2Fzszk8vncMFIbiaaBISBKaicLnnFL2GFwhH4ZFAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: you can't do this without generic, and here is a solution with generic:

```
type MyProxy<T extends string> = T extends keyof paths ?
    ExtractParams<T> : // modify this
    ExtractParams<T>

type knownPathParam = MyProxy<'/a/b/{id}'>
//   ^? type knownPathParam = { id: string }

type unknownPathParam = MyProxy<'/d/e/{id}'>
//   ^? type unknownPathParam = { id: string }
```

I guess you may want to modify the behavior of known paths so I leave `MyProxy` to be conditionally.

---

The reason of **NO** is because `[key in string]: ExtractParams<key>` is not a generic so the `ExtractParams<key>` will be inference immediately, which use `string` as the type parameter to inference

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly this solution doesn't really work for me: I'm trying to type a proxy and your solution would mean that the user has to access it like `proxy<'a/b/c'>['a/b/c'].someMethod` which really doesn't feel great...

Comment: It seems like the generic is not supported for index access, maybe you should try to wrap it with a function or add a method and type on it